# How can you make a div expand to fill the page leaving a fixed amount of area at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I know how to make a div expand to fill the whole page. My problem is that i want to leave a thin band at the top and a thin band at the bottom. The bands can be y amount of pixels. I then want the div in the middle to expand to fill the remaining area.

Everytime I try this it ends up expanding past the bottom of the page. And the only reason I can work out is that the parent DIV is setup to 100% of the height so it is getting its number from that. I have tried using margins and paddings but that is not helping. It still uses 100% of the parent height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like ([this](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/style.css))

A quick breakdown:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {overflow:auto; padding-bottom: 150px;}
#footer {position: relative; margin-top: -150px; height: 150px; clear:both;}
```

This will leave a 150px high "footer" at the bottom of the wrapper div, that will stick to the bottom of the viewport

Oh, and you'll need to add margin & padding = 0 to the body or else you'll see some nasty scrollbars  :(

Comment: I am happy for the footer to move. It doesn't need to be sticky. I would just always like to have a band of background color at the top and a band of background color at the bottom.

Comment: @uriDium Well then rename the footer to "bottom-color" and just give it a background and no content, isn't that the effect your describing here? I mean in theory it's the same?

Comment: HUH? if you don't want the footer to be static then how is it different from a regular flow of 3 divs under each other?

Comment: I guess so. Let me try it and see if it works. Basically I just want the middle portion to always fill the screen. It looks funny if you only have 1 line in there and the middle div shrinks to fit that one line.

Comment: @Bazzz, I don't usually do HTML. So it might be the exact same :) Basically like i said to Daniel in the above. I want the middle div to look like a page and not shrink to a single line if there is not much content. So i want a set amount of space from the top, and from the bottom and the rest to be my content.